# How to pass exceptions in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am Currently working with puppeteer Dart package, as you see in this code below.

```
    try {
            await page.waitForXPath('//*[@id="confirm-yes"]');
            var confirm = await page.$x('//*[@id="confirm-yes"]');
            await confirm[0].click();
          }catch (e) {
              print(e)
           }
```

the code above works fine, i use it on my other tasks, however in this particular step the selector is a popup and it sometimes come up and sometimes doesnt, and so i want it to be like if the popup comes up this above code will identify the selector element and click on it, but if it isnt available than just skip this and move on, however it just gives out an exception and breaks the code. i am very new to dart in python i would have just written pass in exception block.

please help.

Comment: What does this "popup" come from?  How do you "click on it"

Comment: basically when i click login, sometimes a popup comes where it says you are already logged in from another device, do you want to logout from other devices and log in here. btw not paraphrasing it correctly, but you get the idea, that popup only sometimes comes if i am logged in from other device. however i want to bypass it weather it comes or it doesnt so i can move on with the process